# how to fix 500 internal server error in postman using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**service provider detail:**

1. class ServiceProviderDetail extends Model {

   ```
   protected $fillable = [
       'working_status', 'booked', 'title', 'experience', 
   ];    

   public function user()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
   } }
   ```

**add_booking:**

1. class BookingController extends Controller {

   ```
   public function addBooking(Request $request) {
       //return $request;
       $serviceman = ServiceProviderDetail::where('user_id', $request->service_provider_id)->first();
       /********* Check if the serviceman is on duty ********/
       if($serviceman->working_status !=1){
           return response()->json([
               'status'=> 0,
               'message' => "Sorry pro has logged off duty",
               'data' => []
           ], 200);
       }
       $serviceman->booked = '1';
       if($request->input('subservice_id') == ''){
           $service_id = $request->input('service_id');
       } else {
           $service_id = $request->input('subservice_id');
       }

       $booking = new Booking;
       $booking->customer_id = $request->input('customer_id');
       $booking->service_id = $service_id;
       $booking->service_provider_id = $request->input('service_provider_id');
       $booking->latitude = $request->input('latitude');
       $booking->longitude = $request->input('longitude');
       $booking->polyline = $request->input('polyline');
       $booking->servicing_address = $request->input('servicing_address');
       $booking->service_name = $request->input('service_name');
       $booking->service_code = $request->input('service_code');
       $booking->service_mobile = $request->input('service_mobile');
       $booking->service_email = $request->input('service_email');
       $booking->service_date = $request->input('service_date');
       $booking->service_time = $request->input('service_time');
       $booking->status = $request->input('status');

       SendNotification::instance()->sendNotification('You have a new service request.',$booking->service_provider_id);

       if($booking->save()) {
           $serviceman->save();
           return response()->json([
               'status'=> 1,
               'message' => 'Service booked successfully',
               'data' => array(
                   $booking
               ),
           ], 200);
       }
   }
   ```

**error_log:**
*emphasized text*production.ERROR: Trying to get property **'working_status' of non-object** {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to get property 'working_status' of non-object ...../BookingController.php:25)
[stacktrace]

Comment: you can check if is serviceman != null before going forward. or use 

ServiceProviderDetail::where('user_id', $request->service_provider_id)->firstOrFail();

this will throw 404 error

Answer (score 0):

```
$serviceman = ServiceProviderDetail::where('user_id', $request->service_provider_id)->first();
```

This is returning null. check if $serviceman is null before caling values

Comment: how to check this null value?

Comment: if($serviceman) { return response()->json([
            'null'=> true,
        ], 200); }

Comment: I try this checking .....now i get this error :                                           
production.ERROR: Creating default object from empty value {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Creating default object from empty value at ......../BookingController.php:26)
[stacktrace]
if($serviceman) { return response()->json([ 'null'=> true, ], 200); } 
        $serviceman->booked = '1';

Comment: if($serviceman == null) { return response()->json([ 'Status'=> false, ], 200); }